Fluent-Bit - How to extract part of a file name and append it to log_stream_name for Cloudwatch log group
New to Fluent-Bit and looking for some guidance on this.
Latest version of Fluent-Bit is installed on ec2 and successfully running and working.
I am pushing logs from /var/log/nginx... to Cloudwatch
Example, I have logs in /var/log/nginx/client.test-access.log
I want to use Fluent-Bit to extract the 'client.test' and append it to the log_stream_name so that it appears in the Cloudwatch log stream as client.test
I have been trying to use rewrite_tag
    [INPUT]
Name tail
Path /var/log/nginx/*access.log
Tag nginx.access
Path_Key filepath

[FILTER]
Name rewrite_tag
Match nginx.access
# Example assumes log file name is e.g. *.test.com-access.log
# with a destination log group of /aws/ec2/access-logs
Rule $filepath ^/var/log/nginx/(.*)-access.log$ nginx.access.$1
Emitter_Name re_emitted

[OUTPUT]
Name                cloudwatch_logs
Match               nginx.access.*
region              eu-west-2
log_group_name      /aws/ec2/access-logs
log_stream_name     fluent-bit-${TAG[2]}
auto_create_group   true

But it is showing blank in the cloudwatch log stream, can anyone advise if I am doing this correct or is there a better way?
Thanks

If no one knows the answer to this, does anyone know how I can simply append the hostname or ip to the log_stream_name, ie log_stream_name  = log-hostname.

You can try using Record Accessor in combination with Lua to add a domain field extracted from filepath. Then you can append domain to log_stream_name.
From your configuration:
[INPUT]
    Name         tail
    Path         /var/log/nginx/*access.log
    Tag          nginx.access
    Path_Key     filepath

[FILTER]
    Name         lua
    Match        nginx.access
    call         add_domain_field
    script       domain.lua

[OUTPUT]
    Name                cloudwatch_logs
    Match               nginx.access
    region              eu-west-2
    log_group_name      /aws/ec2/access-logs
    log_stream_name     fluent-bit
    log_stream_template fluent-bit-$domain
    auto_create_group   true

And in domain.lua. This file should be in the same directory of your fluentbit configuration:
function add_domain_field(tag, timestamp, record)
    local filepath = record["filepath"]

    -- https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.match
    local domain = string.match(filepath, "^/var/log/nginx/(.*)-access.log$")
    record["domain"] = domain

    -- code 2 means the timestamp is not changed, only the record is changed
    -- https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/lua#return-values
    return 2, timestamp, record
end


Thanks for this I will try on Monday, I had been experimenting a bit with lua script!
I found I can append the hostname by using
[FILTER]
Name          modify
Match         nginx_access
Set           hostname ${HOSTNAME}
as mentioned here
https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/cloudwatch#command-line
Search 'Log Stream and Group Name templating using record_accessor syntax'

The initial question I posted, I am not sure if it is possible, might require a lua script.
